# Can I get my minimized Java app to react to files being dropped on it (on Windows)?

Tags: java, windows, drag-and-drop, minimize

Can I get my minimized Java app to react to files being dropped on it  (on Windows) so that a user can drag files onto the icon on the toolbar and that will cause my application to reopen and process the the files that were dropped on it.

Im using Java 6

Comment: Isn't this default behavior ? I tried to drag a .jpg on a minimized calculator, it expanded automatically. I doubt this is a calc.exe feature :) Is it not working with java apps ?

Comment: No it doesnt work, this is a Java specific question

Comment: I think I got wrong what you mean by "icon on the toolbar" because I'v tried with a java app and it worked, sorry. Do you mean in the main part of the task bar (what I understood), or in the notification area, or in a toolbar in your application ? You should also precise whether you Win7, because it is another story altogether.

Comment: Youve lost me because calc.exe is not a Java app, I do mean the main part of the taskbar and I am running on Windows 7 but the question also applies to Windows Vista & XP. If it works for the app you've tried it maybe because they have coded the solution that I needm, for my own app a No Entry Sign is displayed when I try and drop the files.

Comment: Did you try to add the DropTarget to your Frame/JFrame directly? (Just a guess.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann  ,no I'll try that but I assumed you needed a special library to get it working as you do with recently added apple extensions for Apples version of Java http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.html

Comment: Yeah, may be that this does not help at all (I have no Windows here to try).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermannn checking the code i already do set the drop target for the frame yet it only works when not miminized

Comment: Then it seems that you'll need some windows-specific JNI function :-(

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with pure Java.  Java gives you some level of control over the Frame (the window) but it doesn't give you an API to the toolbar (I assume you mean the bar which corresponds to the Frame you create in the start bar?).  You can create a drop target for something inside your frame like a component (e.g. a JPanel) so that if you drag stuff onto that you will receive dnd events but there is no component that you have access to which maps to the start bar or your Frame's entry in it so there is nothing to add the DropTarget to.